# How to download, then archive and send zip to the user without storing data in RAM and memory?

Tags: asp.net, async-await, zip, bigdata

I need to download photos from S3 via HttpClient, then archive it to zip without compression, and send the archive to the user. However I can't store the zip in RAM, and I cannot create temporary files, because I need to create very large archives (15-20 Gb of data).

I need a solution in C# ASP.

I tried this:

```
var response = HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        response.Headers.Add($"Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename=\"ololo.zip\"");

        await using var outputStream = response.Body;

        using var zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(outputStream);
        zipStream.SetLevel(9);

        for (int i = 0; i < fileUrls.Count; i++)
        {
            var fileName = $"file{i + 1}.jpg";
            var zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
            zipStream.PutNextEntry(zipEntry);

            using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            using var remoteStream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(fileUrls[i]);

            await remoteStream.CopyToAsync(zipStream);
            zipStream.CloseEntry();
        }

        zipStream.IsStreamOwner = false;
        await zipStream.FinishAsync(default);

        return new EmptyResult();
```

But I had errors with async operations. And I tried this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task Zip([FromBody] JsonToZipInput input)
{        
  Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
  Response.Headers.Add($"Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename=\"{input.FileName}\"");

  await Response.StartAsync();
    
  using var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(Response.BodyWriter.AsStream(), ZipArchiveMode.Create);
  foreach (var (key, value) in input.FilePathsToUrls)
  {
    var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(key, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
    await using var zipStream = zipEntry.Open();
    await using var stream = await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync(value);
    await stream.CopyToAsync(zipStream);
  }
}
```

But it loads all archive into the RAM.

Comment: You will need tempfiles. Why exactly can't you s=use them?

Comment: What errors did you have?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to roll your own here. You will need to follow the [PKWare appnote](https://pkwaredownloads.blob.core.windows.net/pem/APPNOTE.txt) with the zip specification. You can look at [zipflow](https://github.com/madler/zipflow), in C, for guidance. Or you can try to convert zipflow to C#. zipflow streams a zip file out without having to store the whole thing in memory or in the file system.